# Does Vue-resource or a community library have an alternative to Angular's Services or Factories?

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

I am working on a larger application using Vue.js and I've been wondering if there is a better way to organize and reuse ajax requests. Currently the application is just making calls within the components (Is that good practice?). I'm coming from Angular, and I was wondering basically if there is an alternative to factories or services?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/aarondfrancis/vue-model ?-

Comment: not quite what I was looking for , but thanks for shaing. As suggested by Linus Borg, I created my own module to organize all my calls in a way I was a little more use too with angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue does not offer any special functionality for this. The recommended way is to simply build your own modules and require them where you need them.